# New message counter

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a simple social app (using firebase and jsqmessagesviewcontroller) and trying to make "new message" counter. Is there any build-in features in firebase to detect if new child was added? I've tried to make in a such way:

```
ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
  self.newMsg += 1
})
```

But this line founds **all** messages, not only new. Is there any build-in feature which help me to handle with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yea child added sees every existing childs and search for new ones. You just want the new ones I think?

Comment: Please review the Firebase docs as this is intended behavior [Work with Lists of Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data) in the Listen For Child Events section. Attaching an observer will read in messages, and then notify of any new ones after that. Use this this to populate a tableView displaying existing messages and notify when there are new ones. Also, take into consideration how to differentiate a new message from an old message - add a flag to mark a message as 'read' - if you do that getting a count of unread messages will be a snap

Answer (score 0):

There is no method for this problem. But I have some ideas on how to approach this.

**Possibility A:**

I would recommend that you store the value of available children on your device. (You could use [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults).) Then if you check for new children you get the new number of all children. You just need do make this calculation in code: `newValueOfChildren - valueOfChildren`. If the result is equal you know there is no new child. If the result is not equal you now how much new children were added. After this calculation you overwrite `valueOfChildren` from `UserDefaults` with `newValueOfChildren`

Let us initialize our variables:

```
let valueOfChildren = UserDefaults.standard
var newValueOfChildren: Int!
```

Let us say you have currently 6 children stored in the Firebase Realtime Database.

```
//How to set user defaults:
valueOfChildren.setInteger(6, forKey: "valueOfChildren")
```

Now I added three children. So there are now 9 children stored in the Firebase Database. Your code to count the existing children must look like this:

```
var newValueOfChildren: Int!
ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) in
    newValueOfChildren = snapshot.childrenCount
}
```

Let us now get the current Int from UserDefaults and assign them to a new variable (`calcValueA`). After that we will calculate:

```
//How to get user defaults:
var calcValueA = defaults.integerForKey("valueOfChildren")

print(newValueOfChildren - calcValueA)
```

The `print()` statement will return this:

> 3

Maybe it's useful to name the variables a bit different. :-)

**Possibility B:**

You could `Firebase Cloud Functions` and use a function on the server that updates and works similar to the described method above or respond to new children with adding 1 to a counter value in your database. You could simply store this in your database and read from a device.

Check out these examples the Firebase team build:

- https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count
- https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/

Comment: Unfortunately, these solutions won't work because they don't take into consideration messages added between the last time the user logged in and now. The app would still need to log into Firebase and count the number of children in the messages node. It also breaks if the user has more than one device (which is common) - trying to keep a count locally is obviously not going to work. It also doesn't explain the behavior the OP comments about - understanding why .childAdded presents the information in the way it does leads to other solutions.

Comment: I mostly agree with you but I don't get why this should not work. You could store the value also in the user data in Firebase.

Comment: How do you get that value? i.e. how would you know which posts are new and how many of them there are?

Comment: You could store the value in the user data of the Firebase user in the database and read it when needed. Where's the problem? The posts generally could have a post date. Also new posts could get an variable in the user data with a post I'd to reference. There are so much ways!

Comment: The OP is asking how to capture only new messages. While your solution offers a way to count messages, it doesn't provide a solution to read in the new messages. Also, your solution Possibility A fails when on Monday there are 10 messages and on Tuesday when they log in in there are 10,000 messages - that's a lot of data to read in by value on a device. Also, as I mentioned, if the user has more than one device Possibility A also fails. Possibility B is going the right direction but still isn't a solution to getting only new messages.