# Count unseen messages with Firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to code a chat app.

I would like to count the number of messages, which are not viewed (unseen).

My database looks like this:

```
user-messages
 |
 |_messages
    |
    |_UserID1
    |   |
    |   |_UserID2
    |     |
    |     |_ MessageID1
    |     |_ MessageID2
    |     |_ MessageID3
    |     |_ etc...
    |     
    |_UserID2
    |   |
    |   |_UserID1
    |     |
    |     |_ MessageID1
    |     |_ MessageID2
    |     |_ MessageID3
    |     |_ etc...
```

And for the Messages object:

```
messages
 |
 |_messageID1
 |  |
 |  |_ notViewed: false / true
 |  |_ text: "Message text"
 |  |_ timestamp: 1522230692
 |  |_ etc...
 |  
 |_messageID2
 |  |
 |  |_ notViewed: false / true
 |  |_ text: "Message text"
 |  |_ timestamp: 1522230692
 |  |_ etc...
```

I arrived to get all the message ID which are linked to a specific user:

```
var REF_MESSAGE = Database.database().reference().child("messages")
var REF_USER_MESSAGE = Database.database().reference().child("user-messages").child("messages")


func fetchUnviewedMessages(withId id: String, completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void ) {

      REF_USER_MESSAGE.child(id).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

         let userId = snapshot.key as String

         self.REF_USER_MESSAGE.child(id).child(userId).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            let messageId = snapshot.key

                // This part is where I have a problem
                self.fetchMessageNotViewed(messageId, completion: { (nbMessageNotRead)  in
                   completion(nbMessageNotRead)
                })
             })
          }
    }
```

But I don't know what I need to do with that list, to observe the number of unseen messages ...

I tried that, but without success:

```
func fetchMessageNotViewed(_ messageId: String, completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
      guard let currentUid = Api.User.CURRENT_USER?.uid else {
         return
      }

      REF_MESSAGE.child(messageId).queryOrdered(byChild: "notViewed").queryEqual(toValue: true).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

         let count = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
         print(count)
      }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Comment: You want unseen messages of each user or all the users?

Comment: I want to count unseen message for a specific user, in order to let him know he has new messages (or not) with a dot in the tabBar

Comment: What is `REF_USER_MESSAGE ` ?? tell me the whole node.

Comment: May be this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562990/new-message-counter

Comment: @aBilal17 thanks but there is no answer it this topic :/

Comment: you can possibly use a counter for this. Like for and example i have used an scenario where i was using an UserDefault key in which i was storing the count of array in which i was getting the response of message. and every time user reads the message, i used to make the count of it back to 0.And if user does not read any so you need to add the current response to existing value of the UserDefault variable. If you want i can make a sample code for you.

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore yes why not, I don't see how I could do this ...

Comment: @dahiya_boy I edited my first post

Comment: @KevinB With **REF_MESSAGE** you get each and every `messageID`, so why didn't you put the for-loop and check whether the msg is seen or not with child `notViewed ` and use count to calculate the unread msgs.

Answer (score 3):

We can leverage a compound value to handle this fairly easily.

Make a simple change to the Firebase structure messages node:

```
messages
 |
 |_messageID1
 |  |
 |  |_ notViewed: false / true
 |  |_ text: "Message text"
 |  |_ timestamp: 1522230692
 |  |_ forUid_status: "UserId1_unread"   //<- Compound value
 |  |_ etc...
 |  
 |_messageID2
 |  |
 |  |_ notViewed: false / true
 |  |_ text: "Message text"
 |  |_ timestamp: 1522230692
 |  |_ forUid_status: "UserId1_read"   //<- Compound value
 |  |_ etc...
```

then a simple query will reveal a count of UserId1 unread messages

```
let messagesRef = self.ref.child("messages")
let uid = "UserId1"
let status = "unread"
let queryString = uid + "_" + status //results in a string UserId1_unread

let ref = messagesRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "forUid_status").queryEqual(toValue: queryString)
ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        let count = snapshot.childrenCount
        print("unread messages: \(count)")
    } else {
        print("no unread messages")
    }
})
```

running this code against the above Firebase results in

```
unread messages: 1
```

This may also help with the loading of unread messages as not only can you get their count but adding the observer to that node will also notify the app any time a new unread message is added for UserId1

Comment: In this case, when we changed to 'unread' to 'read' status then what need to do?. we need to update each and every message with user status(forUid_status) to 'read'

Comment: @razesh If the objective is to keep track of messages that have been read and also ones that have not been read then each message would need to have their status updated as they change from unread to read so yes. Just a simple change that that one node within each message would work well.

Answer (score 0):

As on request by @KevinB

You can use my logic to show the counter in message popup

**Step:-1** WebService call/Firebase Fetch:

Fetch the array of message data in app.In my case, i was having an array of messages in response and store the count of it an userDefault.
For E.g:-

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(arrMessageData.count, forKey: "messageCount")
```

**Step:-2** Set Counter-Zero when message is read Or Appending the old value with new value

**Case:1 Reading the Message**

In my case i was having a separate popup for reading the message. when that pop-up was opened i was forcefully making the value of my userDefault value to 0

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(0, forKey: "messageCount")
```

**Case:1 If message is un-read**

In that case if pop-up is not opened so in that case there will be some value in userDefault. In this case First fetch the current count in userDefault and then make the WSCall and get the new count and Add both and then save in same key.

**Note:-** The idea of storing the counter in userDefault is used because it can be accessed anywhere in app and can directly be shown in any label or button.

Comment: I don't think the second step can work. I can have more than 1 discussion, so I can read a discussion and still have unseen messages

Comment: for that you can use and array or can take support of local database.Like you can manage an key-Value pair and then can manage the counter discussion wise in DB or an array of dictionaries.You can use the same logic to update the counter to zero or append the old value